# Best way to insert ranking (SQL database with php)

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-server

```
UserID  Rank  TotalRevenue  TotalDishesSold
1550    0     908           45
1141    0     985           67
1402    0     637           34
1063    0     736           89 
1204    0     26            78
```

Hi, this is the first time I am doing SQL using php. What is the best way/efficient to sort the database according to TotalRevenue then TotalDishesSold and insert a rank to each user? I will have 100k of user.

Comment: You have to retrieve record order by `TotalRevenue` and `TotalDishesSold` DESC then In loop using counter you can give rank one by one

Answer (score 2):

you can order using ROW_NUMBER()

```
SELECT UserID, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY TotalRevenue DESC, TotalDishesSold DESC), 
       TotalRevenue, TotalDishesSold
FROM   TableName
```

Use Temp Table to store the UserID and Rank. Then join with your table and update the Rank

**Temp table**

```
INSERT INTO @Temp (UserID, Rank)
SELECT UserID, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY TotalRevenue DESC, TotalDishesSold DESC)
FROM   TableName
```

**Update your table**

```
UPDATE  T SET
        T.Rank = T1.Rank
FROM    TableName AS T INNER JOIN
        @Temp AS T1 ON T1.UserID = T.UserID
```